# OTA firmware update with BLE113

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, gatt, ota, bluegiga

I want to do firmware update over the air with BLE113 module. I am using Nordic's nRF Toolbox to test this and I have configured their GATT services and characteristics in BGScript to do OTA update. But OTA updates are not always successful.

I deduce that, according to Nordic there are different file types of file that can be used to upload for OTA update process, which are,

1. Distribution Packet(ZIP)
2. Soft Device
3. Bootloader
4. Application.

At present I use 'Application' which means I select a bin file and upload with nRF Toolbox app from Android mobile. But this method is mostly unsuccessful (success rate is nearly 10% only). Can anyone suggest me a reliable way to do this? Has file type got to do anything with reliable OTA update process?

**EDIT :**
I am using a custom made board. I am not sure with antenna, Anyway I shall check this. And I always keep optimum power level. But nRF Toolbox (or I have come up with my own app using Nordic's OTA firmware update library) always shows 'successfully transferred' when I do OTA update and firmware is not updated most of the times.

Comment: Are you using a custom made board or one from the development kit? You could have a poor antenna causing unreliable data transfer. Try checking the power level of the radio signal just in case.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Christophe. Please see the edit.

Comment: I found the issue that signal interference is causing unreliable data transfer and memory on my board was not sufficient too. The performance is better after resolving these two issues.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to update a Bluegiga BLE 113 with Nordic's toolbox? That can't work.

Nordic and Bluegiga (now Silicon Labs) have different ways to perform firmware updates over the air, and they're not compatible.

I have a sample iOS app which will let you OTA from an iOS device to the BLE113 (assuming your firmware supports it): https://github.com/RobotPajamas/ble113-ota-ios

Here is a longer explanation of the BLE113 over the air update process: http://www.sureshjoshi.com/embedded/ble113-ota-over-the-air-programming/